# How to remove focus from Kendo UI AutoComplete when an Item is selected and set focus on an input element?

Tags: autocomplete, kendo-ui

I am trying to shift focus from a Kendo UI AutoComplete to an input element after an item has been selected. I've tried this...

```
select: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    vm.selectedProductID(dataItem.ProdID);
    $('#itemQtyBox').focus();
}
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you cannot change focus from inside `select` handler... maybe it's acceptable for you wait a little and then do it. I mean:

```
select    : function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#itemQtyBox").focus();
    }, 100);
}
```

What I do is set a timeout (in the previous example 0.1 seconds) and then change focus (I know that it is not nice but works).

Comment: Not sure why this is necessary, but it worked for me as well.